# Which should we choose between Effect and Either as a return type of our business services?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

With the arrival of Arrow 1.1.x we got the new [Effect](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core.continuations/-effect/) class.

Up to now, my business classes returned Either to model the effect of returning an error or a value, e.g.:

```
    @Service
    class CreateDepartmentUseCaseImpl(
        private val createDepartmentsDrivenPort: CreateDepartmentsDrivenPort,
        private val getDepartmentByCodeDrivenPort: GetDepartmentByCodeDrivenPort
    ) : CreateDepartmentUseCase {
        override suspend fun execute(param: Department): Either<DomainError, Department> =
            Either.conditionally(getDepartmentByCodeDrivenPort.get(param.code) == null,
                { DepartmentAlreadyExistsError(param.code.value) },
                { createDepartmentsDrivenPort.create(param) })

    }
```

With the new `Effect` this could be refactored to something like:

```
    @Service
    class CreateDepartmentUseCaseImpl(
        private val createDepartmentsDrivenPort: CreateDepartmentsDrivenPort,
        private val getDepartmentByCodeDrivenPort: GetDepartmentByCodeDrivenPort
    ) : CreateDepartmentUseCase {
        override suspend fun execute(param: Department): Effect<DomainError, Department> = effect {
            ensure(getDepartmentByCodeDrivenPort.get(param.code) == null) { DepartmentAlreadyExistsError(param.code.value) }
            createDepartmentsDrivenPort.create(param)
        }
    }
```

In tests, the mocking changed from:

```
    @Test
    fun `should create department`() = runTest {
        val dep = createValidDepartment()
        val createDepartmentRequest = CreateDepartmentRequest(dep.code.value, dep.name.value, dep.description.value)
        `when`(createDepartmentsUseCase.execute(dep)).thenReturn(dep.right())
```

to...

```
    @Test
    fun `should create department`() = runTest {
        val dep: Department = createValidDepartment()
        val createDepartmentRequest = CreateDepartmentRequest(dep.code.value, dep.name.value, dep.description.value)
        `when`(createDepartmentsUseCase.execute(dep)).thenReturn(effect { dep })
```

The question is, what's the best approach to model our business services, the new `Effect` class or `Either`, and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no reason to refactor to `Effect` if `Either` fits your use case.

> The question is, what's the best approach to model our business services, the new Effect class or Either, and why?

Sadly as often in software, there is no 1-fit-all answer but to model business services I would in general recommend `Either`.
`Effect<E, A>` is semantically equivalent to `suspend EffectScope<E>.() -> A`, and the result of running that lambda can be `Either<E, A>`.

That is also why we can assign `Effect` to a `val`, and when returning `Either` we need to *invoke* the suspend lambda which requires `suspend fun`.

```kotlin
val operation: Effect<E, A> =
  effect { ... }

suspend fun operation(): Either<E, A> =
  operation.toEither()
```

So if you just need to model the *result* of an operation then using `Either<E, A>` is desired. If you need to pass around a lambda/operation then using `Effect` can be used.

You can consider `Effect` a lower level implementation than `Either`, since all computation blocks such as `either { }`, `option { }`, `ior { }`, `result { }`, etc are now all implemented through `effect`.

Which you can see in the Arrow implementation for `either { }`.

```kotlin
suspend fun <E, A> either(block: suspend EffectScope<E>.() -> A): Either<E, A> =
  effect(block).toEither()
```

Comment: I've been wondering about this too.  Thanks OP and @nomisRev.